# How to solve this minimization (maximization)?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, optimization, discrete-optimization

I'm facing this problem:

> $$ \large
> \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}_+^3} \max \left\{ { \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^2-2 x_1 x_3 \over \left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i \right)^2} , { \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^2 + 2 (x_1 x_3 - x_1x_2+x_2x_3) \over \left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i \right)^2} \right\}
> $$

I don't know how to deal with inner $\max$ and choose one of two!

I'm trying to use $max(A,B) \geq \frac12(A+B)$!
Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What are $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$? If they are unspecified, what does it even mean to pick a max from the two quantities in the braces? Why is the $\min$ over $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$ if there isn't even a non-subscripted $x$ in the braces?

Comment: Something is wrong here. Maybe it should read $x \in \mathbb{R}_+^{\color{red}{3}}$?

Comment: @VedranŠego Yes you are right. I corrected it. Thank you and `blf`

Comment: @blf Actually the most difficult part of the problem is what you've stated! But it is a part of the problem and it is right

Comment: First as it's homogeneous, we can suppose x1+x2+x3=1. Then for h(x)=max{f(x),g(x)}, if f(x) and g(x) has some common points, then min{h(x)|x in R}=min{h(x)|f(x)=g(x)}. Is it right?

Comment: @delta Yes, since the solution is independent of $||x||_2$ and is a function of its angle, we can assume $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$

But, what is the reason of your second claim, and how it helps? Thanks

Comment: denote the two as f(x1,x2,x3) and g(x1,x2,x3),let xi'=xi/(x1+x2+x3), you can check that f(x1',x2',x3')=f(x1,x2,x3), and so does g(x), and x1'+x2'+x3'=1, so we can suppose x1+x2+x3=1.(it's a common trick in "homogeneous", I am not sure if I use the right word in English). For the second claim, you can check x around the x which f(x)=g(x), they all larger than f(x). Actually I don't have an exactly proof, I thought it is right. If it is right, then we have x1+x2+x3=1,f(x)=g(x), our aim is min{f(x)|f(x)=g(x)}, 3 variables, two constraint equation(Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: @delta I didn't got what you meant on your second claim! You mean generally or just for the case?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi consider less variables, such as min{max(x^2,x-1)}, draw a graph may help. I thought it's a general case, I don't have a proof now, still working on it.

Comment: I think, for h(x)=min{max{f(x),g(x)}}, h(x)=min{max({f(x),g(x)}|f(x)=g(x) or x on borders}. with x1+x2+x3=1,g(x)=x1^2+x2^2+x3^2+2(x1x3−x1x2+x2x3)=1-4x1x2, f(x)=g(x), got $x_2=(1-4x_1-(8x_1^2+1)^{0.5})$, then h(x)=min{1-4x1x2}=min{function with x1}, and need to check the borders.  mathematica:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min%5Bmax%5Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%2B%281-x-y%29%5E2-2*x%281-x-y%29%2C1-4*xy%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2C1-x%7D%5D%5D

Answer (score 1):

A standard trick when dealing with max-min or min-max problem is to introduce a new decision variable, call it $z$, which models the inner optimization. Hence, your objective function becomes
$$ \min_{z \in \mathbb{R}, \bf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3_+} z $$
with the following constraints
$$\begin{aligned}
z &\geq \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^2-2 x_1 x_3}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i \right)^2} \\
z &\geq \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^2 + 2 (x_1 x_3 - x_1x_2+x_2x_3)}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i \right)^2} \\
\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i &= 1
\end{aligned}$$
The first two inequalities model the $\max$ expression, i.e. they state that whatever $z$ comes out to be, it has to be larger than either of the two terms. The last one captures the homogeneity, as it has been pointed out in the comments. From here, you can apply the KKT conditions.